# Analyze VMDK (vmware virtual machine disk) files for changes

Tags: filesystems, virtual-machine, vmware

Is there a good way to analyze VMware delta VMDK files between snapshots to list changed blocks, so one can use a tool to tell which NTFS files are changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know a tool that does this out of the block, but it should not be so difficult.

The VMDK file format specification is available and the format is not that complex. As far as I remember, a VMDK file consists of a lot of 64k block. At the beginning of the VMDK file there is some directory that contains the information where a logical block is stored in the physical file.

It should be pretty easy to detect there a logical block is stored in both files and than compare the data in the two version of the VMDK file.

Comment: Thanks dmeister. I've already examined the VMDK format. Even no need for a comparison this time, as delta files are differential. I too was unable to find a tool which simply lists the blocks / sectors a sparse VMDK file contains. So I think I'll turn this into a project. Your answer can help others, I'm marking it as the best answer.